# Как развернуть django на сервере

Tags: django

Имеется сервере ОС ubuntu. Скачал питон, сделал виртуальную среду, скачал джанго, создал проект, мигрировал бд, запускаю. Сервер работает по адресу 127.0.0.1:8000. Работает реально он или нет на локалке не могу проверить, так как сервер удаленный. Вопрос такой, я запускаю сервер через интерактивную консоль и если консоль закрываю сервер тоже закрывается я так понимаю. Как запустить его, что бы он работал постоянно? И как его запустить, что бы можно было заходить не только с локального, но и удаленного компьютера на сайт.

Comment: разверни в докере + задай айпишник, что бы через него могли заходить другие

Comment: Во-первых, запускать боевой сервер через команду runserver категорически нельзя, так как runserver предназначен только для локальной разработки, медленный и небезопасный. Во-вторых, в документации Django есть целая отдельная страница о том, как его разворачивать https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/index.html

Comment: В-третьих, перед Django крайне рекомендуется поставить nginx и настроить раздачу статики через него для улучшения производительности. В-четвёртых, перед изменениями на реальном сервере потренируйтесь в виртуальной машине

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо большое, просто запустить получилось сейчас буду пробовать Gunicornом

Comment: @andreymal во всех туториалах пишут, что для запуска нужен файл `wsgi`, например, `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 project.wsgi` откуда берется файл `project.wsgi`? Когда создаем проект на джанго командами startproject startapp такого файла не появляется

Comment: @helldrg неправда, при startproject он появляется

Comment: появляется `manage.py` и в отдельной папке 5 питоновских файлов: `__init__.py`, `asgi.py`, `settings.py`, `urls.py`, `wsgi.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

Для запуска

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:<нужный порт>
```

И если есть сетевой доступ, порт открыт, то должно подключиться. Но такая конфигурация годится только для разработки и небезопасна.

Comment: Спасибо помогло! Я думал нужно будет как то порты открывать на убунте и шаманить =)

Comment: @helldrg в большинстве линуксов все порты открыты по умолчанию, если вы их сами не закрыли каким-нибудь фаерволом (и их кстати лучше закрыть для повышения безопасности)